# remove first number from height variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var height = $("#divOne").height();
```

How to remove first number from height variable?

for example if height of this element is 118 I want to be 18.

Comment: if you want the last 2 digits then `height = $("#divOne").height() % 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var height = $("#divOne").height().toString();

height = height.substring(1,height.length);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/gkhbct1u/2/)**

Comment: `height` is a number.

Answer (score 2):

First convert it into string then use the substring function.

```
var height = $("#divOne").height();
height = (height.toString()).substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the remainder from 100.

```
var height = $("#divOne").height();
height = height%100;
console.log(height);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/gkhbct1u/4/)

Comment: Note that `18%100 = 18`

Comment: This may fail for 4 digit number height though it is depending upon OPs requirement.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar NO it shouldn't.